# Maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Is maximum modulus principle obeyed by antiholomorphic functions. I think it should be as they are the functions of z conjugate alone and not z .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the maximum modulus principle also holds for antiholomorphic functions.

I think the easiest argument is that antiholomorphic functions are precisely the conjugates of holomorphic functions, and the modulus is invariant under conjugation. Thus the maximum modulus principle holds for a class $\mathscr{C}$ of functions if and only if it holds for the class of the conjugates of the elements of $\mathscr{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum modulus principle holds for [harmonic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) and holomorphic or antiholomorphic functions are harmonic functions.